# How my app save and open photos from the iPhone's photo library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I save and open photos from the iPhone's photo library from my app?
Code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is saved off a picked photo in your own app writable directory, and use that going forward... note that if you save out to the users library multiple times, it will create a new image every time.

You may want to file a [Radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/wa/signIn) with Apple to allow direct access to the file, or give you some kind of reference you could use to see the file (to see EXIF for example).

Answer (score 1):

This allows you to save an image to the photo album:

```
// Adds a photo to the saved photos album.  The optional completionSelector should have the form:
//  - (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo;
UIKIT_EXTERN void UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);
```

(sample code: )

```
IImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum( image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil );  


/// called function, alerts user when the image has been saved:

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {
    [ [ self parentViewController ] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];   
}
```

Comment: How can the image be reopened without the user having to pick the image from a UIImagePickerController the next time I launch my app?

Comment: Unfortunately, after doing some digging, it may be that part is not possible for applications released via the AppStore.  You can save them to both the Album and your own directory (and you can open the ones in your own directory with no problem), but it does not appear that applications have access to the camera's photo album.